# How to use secrets.yml in ruby on rails 4 to store a password in database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, passwords

I have a ruby on rails 4 project and my config/secrets.yml looks like this:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: verylongnumber
  postgres: 'mypassword'
```

My config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: myusername
  password: 'mypassword' # <-- Problem here
```

What do I need to type in password in my config/database.yml, to get the password from secrets.yml?

I tried:

```
password: <%= ENV['postgres'] %>
password: <%= ENV["postgres"] %>
password: <%= ENV[postgres] %>
password: ENV['postgres']
password: ENV["postgres"]
password: ENV[postgres]
```

But neither of these solutions worked. Where did I go wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `<%= Rails.application.secrets[:your_key] %>` to access the value of `secrets.yml`.

The below should work

`<%= Rails.application.secrets[:postgres] %>`

I strongly recommend you to have a look at this blog

https://launchschool.com/blog/managing-environment-configuration-variables-in-rails

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer and your suggestion are both very useful.

Comment: Such an amazing blog!